# Consuming WCF service using net named pipe binding in asp .net core 2.0 api

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core, .net-core, netnamedpipebinding

Is it possible to consume WCF service using net named pipe binding in asp .net core 2.0 api?

There is always option to make WCF service to use http enabled binding. But I have a specific requirement to do that?

I didnt find any useful resources on google.

Comment: Did you look at [WCF for .NET Core 2.0.0](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/releases)?

Comment: @Tim Yep. I cant see it has support for NetNamedPipes.

Comment: It does support CustomBindings - you might be able to replicate Named Pipes that way (not 100% sure).  It currently supports basicHttpBinding, customBinding, NetHttpBinding, NetTcpBinding (https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/release-notes/SupportedFeatures-v2.0.0.md)

Comment: This might help [`<namedPipeTransport>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/namedpipetransport)

Comment: Unfortunately not available in .net core 2.0